# javascript. alert when sound plays

Tags: javascript

I am basically trying to make a auto better on earn.gg (dice)

Is there a way to alert("win") if a sound is playing in the chrome tab? I will run the script in the console of that tab.

I have tried to do "roll();" in the console and it rolled the dice and returned me "value:false" because i lost and when i win it returns me value:true.So i figured to use that and make the code below. That simply didn't work and returned me "win" every time. Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/fpeoxb

```
roll();
if(value=true){
   console.log("win");
}else if(value=false){
   console.log("lose");
}
```

Comment: The problem is if condition must be `==` not `=`. but in this case I guess you cannot check the `value == true | false` because it's in `state`, not the global/window variable

Comment: yea the "==" still didn't work.

Comment: can u share the fiddle of your code

Comment: as I told you. `value` isn't global/window variable, so that you cannot check it. (it's always `undefined` I guess)

Comment: ok, but is there a way to alert("win"); if sound is being played in the tab? Because when you win there is a sound played.